# Jasper Reports Image Servlet in Liferay

Tags: java, jasper-reports, portlet, liferay-6

I've created a portlet using Liferay CE 6.1 that queries an Oracle Database and displays HTML, PDF and Excel reports from Jasper 4.5.  I am trying to get the HTML reports to display images.  I have images in my PDF and Excel Reports.  The reports are being called correctly from this I can believe since the information appears there with the dynamic queries working properly.  I believe I have this set correctly but I can not get the images to display.  I'm new to Java so I'm trying to determine the best way to debug this.  My code is here:

Report Generation Code:

```
Connection conn = myconnection.getconnection;
JasperPrint print = null;
String reportPath = "/html/reports/MyReport.jasper";

PortletContext context = getPortletContext();
InputStream reportStream = context.getResourceAsStream(reportPath);
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportStream, map, conn);
```

HTML Exporter Class:

```
JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
request.getPortletSession().setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE,printObject);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, printObject);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STRING_BUFFER, outputBuffer);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, "../servlets/image?image=");
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND,java.lang.Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.exportReport();
```

And I have this code in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets/image</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Everywhere I read makes me believe I have this right, but I am getting nothing in the HTML version.  The PDF and XLS versions of the reports all show the graphics and graphs.  Any clues on how to debug this or troubleshoot this and track it down?

Thanks,
George

Comment: have you tried to remove the `..` from your `IMAGES_URI` parameter?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  I got nowhere.  I switched to BIRT with the portlet from Visioneo and haven't gone back.  I had graphics and interactivity done in half the time.